# Installing GUI on Ubuntu

Tags: gnome, gui

I have installed a Ubuntu Server and executed the command sudo command to install the ubuntu-desktop. Now when I log in I get a graphical prompt for my password but after I login it seems to take alot of time. I have heard that something call GNOME is faster. How do I install it. Again I apologize but I am relatively new to Ubuntu but not Linux. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Gnome classic is a lighter desktop than unity / Ubuntu Desktop. You can install gnome by using the following command:

```bash
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

Then on the login screen, you can selet gnome from a list:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is off the topic but once I am logged in with the GNOME desktop how do I log out?

Comment: on the shutdown button next to the clock, there is a `Log Out` option.

Comment: I am sorry but I see 'Activities' on the far left upper corner, the clock in the center of the top, and what I can best describe as 'Preferences' on the left (a button with the image of a person), Then some disabled buttons (that seem to be connected with sound), and finally my name (which has no drop down or way of selecting it.

Comment: hold the alt key and right click the panel, select `Add to panel` and then double click the `Log Out` option.